# opencv mouse callback isn't being triggered

Tags: python, callback, opencv

Take a look at this function:

```
def showImage(im):
    def printColor(event, x, y, flag, params):
        if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            print(im[x,y])
            sys.exit(1)

    tag = "image"
    cv2.setMouseCallback(tag, printColor)
    cv2.imshow(tag, im)
    while True:
        if 'q' == chr(cv2.waitKey() & 255):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

It's supposed to display an image and print the pixel at mouse position when clicked. But for some reason the callback isn't being triggered. How can I get this code working?

Comment: You say it prints the coordinates of the mouse when clicked.. In your code that's what the callback function does..

Comment: @AdamMitchell I've tried to run this code and it doesn't print anything when I click the mouse. The `sys.exit` line is proof that the callback isn't being triggered.

Comment: Take care with your indentation. Is this exactly how your code is? The code from `tag` onwards should not be inside the function `showImage`.

Comment: @saga You're very unclear. You literally say *"It displays an image and prints the pixel at mouse position when clicked"*. Maybe you should edit your question to be more clear.

Comment: @Bonlenfum the `printColor` is local to `showImage` everything else works fine. The window closes when I press `q`. The only problem is with the callback.

Comment: @AdamMitchell Pardon me for the error, I've fixed the question.

Comment: Have you tried printing `event` to see what event you're actually catching? And is `tag` *definitely* the name of the window in which you wish to catch the event?

Comment: @AdamMitchell A print statement at the beginning of printColor doesn't print anything. That's why I think that the callback is being ignored.

Comment: Try to add `setMouseCallback` after `imshow`.

Comment: @DmitriiZ. That worked, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `setMouseCallback` to work you will need to create window object first.

This can be done either by calling `imshow` before setting mouse callback, or by creating it with [cv2.namedWindow()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5afdf8410934fd099df85c75b2e0888b)

Answer (score 0):

@You may try the following code

```
import cv2

def function1(event, x, y, flags, param):

    if event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:


        print(input_img[x, y])


input_img = cv2.imread(r'D:\personal 
data\316817146_6028126817205901_1035125390140549057_n.jpg') # get image
#named window
cv2.namedWindow('new window')
#show the image in the window
cv2.imshow('new window', input_img)

#call setMouseCallback()
cv2.setMouseCallback('new window', function1)

while True:

    if cv2.waitKey(1) and 0xFF==ord('q'):

        break


cv2.detroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you explain why this code solves the problem in the question?